# Parity-L vs. NL

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, counting-complexity

Parity-L, also known as $\oplus$L, is the set of languages recognized by a non-deterministic Turing machine which can only distinguish between an even number or odd number of "acceptance" paths. A recent [related question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/175/what-are-the-consequences-of-parity-l-p) was asked by Niel de Beaudrap.

My question is the following:

> Do we know if  NL $\subseteq$ $\oplus$L? Or are these two classes believed to be incomparable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Non-uniformly, NL is contained in parity-L: see http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/W94/proc.pdf

Comment: The result has been extended by Reinhardt and Allender (see http://ftp.cs.rutgers.edu/pub/allender/nlul.pdf)